# Java error - "invalid method declaration; return type required"

Tags: java

We are learning how to use multiple classes in `Java` now, and there is a project asking about creating a class `Circle` which will contain a `radius` and a `diameter`, then reference it from a main class to find the diameter. This code continues to receive an error (mentioned in the title)

```
public class Circle
{
    public CircleR(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
    }
    public diameter()
    {
        double d = radius * 2;
        return d;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help, -AJ

**Update 1**:
Okay, but I shouldn't have to declare the third line `public CircleR(double r)` as a double, right? In the book I am learning from, the example doesn't do that.

```
public class Circle 

    { 
        //This part is called the constructor and lets us specify the radius of a  
      //particular circle. 
      public Circle(double r) 
      { 
       radius = r; 
      } 

      //This is a method. It performs some action (in this case it calculates the 
        //area of the circle and returns it. 
        public double area( )  //area method 
      { 
          double a = Math.PI * radius * radius; 
       return a; 
    } 

    public double circumference( )  //circumference method 
    { 
      double c = 2 * Math.PI * radius; 
     return c; 
    } 

        public double radius;  //This is a State Variable…also called Instance 
         //Field and Data Member. It is available to code 
    // in ALL the methods in this class. 
     }
```

As you can see, the code `public Circle(double r)....` how is that different from what I did in mine with `public CircleR(double r)`? For whatever reason, no error is given in the code from the book, however mine says there is an error there.

Comment: Javac is usually quite helpful and the error messages it returns are quite clear. Next time you have one of these have a short break and the answer will come to you :)

Comment: `CircleR` is not a constructor for `Circle`. The names *must* match.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> As you can see, the code public Circle(double r).... how is that
>   different from  what I did in mine with public CircleR(double r)? For
>   whatever reason, no error  is given in the code from the book, however
>   mine says there is an error there.

When defining constructors of a class, they should have the same name as its class.
Thus the following code

```
public class Circle
{ 
    //This part is called the constructor and lets us specify the radius of a  
    //particular circle. 
  public Circle(double r) 
  { 
   radius = r; 
  }
 ....
}
```

is correct while your code

```
public class Circle
{
    private double radius;
    public CircleR(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
    }
    public diameter()
    {
       double d = radius * 2;
       return d;
    }
}
```

is wrong because your constructor has different name from its class. You could either follow the same code from the book and change your constructor from

```
public CircleR(double r)
```

to

```
public Circle(double r)
```

or (if you really wanted to name your constructor as CircleR) rename your class to CircleR.

So your new class should be

```
public class CircleR
{
    private double radius;
    public CircleR(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
    }
    public double diameter()
    {
       double d = radius * 2;
       return d;
    }
}
```

I also added the return type double in your method as pointed out by Froyo and John B.

Refer to this [article](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor.html) about constructors.

HTH.

Comment: ok, but now it is highlighting the radius = r; portion and saying "cannot find symbol - variable class". and thanks for the article, i'm reading it now.

Comment: never mind, i realized that at the bottom, i need to say public double radius;. what is the reason for this, though? why do i state that at the bottom rather than right there inside of the public Circle(double r)?

Comment: Because...  'double r' is a parameter to the constructor.  'double radius;', outside of any method, is a field in the class.  Parameters are discarded when the method returns.  Fields exist as long as the class instance.

Comment: (P.S. 'private' would be more appropriate than 'public' for the 'double radius;' field.)

Comment: @Alex My bad, I should have noticed that your constructor's radius variable isn't defined anywhere. Anyways, I edited the code and added the private double radius field. Glad you liked the link I provided, here's another for defining methods in Java: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Comment: @Alex I mentioned earlier that if you wanted to change your constructor's name to CircleR you need to change your class name to CircleR too. I forgot to mention that Java files should be share the same name as its class. For example, public class Circle must be saved as Circle.java and public class CircleR as CircleR.java. Happy programming!

Answer (score 9):

Every method (other than a constructor) must have a return type.

```
public double diameter(){...
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to declare double as a return type

```
public double diameter()
{
    double d = radius * 2;
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue when adding a class to the main method. Turns out it wasn't an issue, it was me not checking my spelling. So, as a noob, I learned that mis-spelling can and will mess things up. These posts helped me "see" my mistake and all is good now.