# invalid method declaration; return type required android studio

Tags: android

Help me please
Error: (8, 12) error: invalid method declaration; Return type required

```
    public NavDrawerItem() {

}

public NavDrawerItem(boolean showNotify, String title) {
    this.showNotify = showNotify;
    this.title = title;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class has the name `navdraw` yet you are creating constructors for `NavDrawerItem`. Because of that, the Java compiler thinks that you actually wanted to create simple methods and ask for a return type, e.g. `public int NavDrawerItem() { }` (**This will not work**)

**Solution**: Rename youe class to `NavDrawerItem`

Answer (score 0):

When making a new constructor, the constructor's name must have the exact name as the class name, in this case navdraw.

You need to research for the error to find the solution.
Duplicate : [Java error - "invalid method declaration; return type required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451707/java-error-invalid-method-declaration-return-type-required)