# method overloading in java program error

Tags: java

```
class Test {
    int x, y;

    calc(int a) {
        x = a;
        System.out.println("Square is " + (x * x));
    }

    calc(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        System.out.println("Addition is " + (x + y));
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj = new Test();
        obj.calc(10, 20);
        obj.calc(10);
    }
}
```

> ```
> methodOverloading.java:3: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
>     calc(int a){
>     ^
> methodOverloading.java:7: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
>     calc(int a,int b){
>     ^
> 2 errors
> ```

What's wrong?

Comment: Methods must declare a return type (e.g `void`) .

Comment: Hint: try using a search engine the next time, before putting up a new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451707/java-error-invalid-method-declaration-return-type-required

Answer (score 3):

Methods have to define a return type, like

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

declares `void` as return type (that is "return nothing, just do something in the method").

Since your methods seem to calculate multiplications and additions but don't return anything, you should give them a corresponding return type:

```
void calc(int a)
```

and

```
void calc(int a, int b)
```

In case you want that method not to print the result but return it, you would have to adjust the return type and add a return statement in the method body, like this:

```
int calc(int a) {
    // returns the square of a, which is again an integer
    return a * a;
}
```

Comment: thanks bro , my program is done!!!

Comment: @BhargaModh Very good... Do you mind accepting the answer?